# How can i call a web-component with a script call

Tags: javascript, iframe, web-component

I developed a web app with react and i want to embed it in another website, although i embedded it in the website through an iframe, there is a code below about it.

```
<iframe src="https://mapbox-project.netlify.app/" frameborder="0" height="560" width="100%"></iframe>
```

But, due to iframes limitations, i want to be able to embed it through a script call like this instead?
I don't know if this might help to understand what I'm trying to achieve here.. https://blog.jenyay.com/web-ui-widget/

```
  <script src="https://mapbox-project.netlify.app/"></script>
```

But i really do not know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible. The only ways to embed another page is via an iframe, actual frames (if anyone still remembers them), or using embed. Script tags are for executing javascript code, but a page is not javascript code. Some web applications/APIs offer a JSONP variant for embedding where you can indeed call them via a script tag, e.g., but that would need to be enabled by the embedded application and requires additional work.

Comment: But this article is saying otherwise https://blog.jenyay.com/web-ui-widget/

Comment: No, it's not. That article describes one of those ways in which a web application can make itself embeddable via a script tag, just like I said. And just like I also said that's extra work on behalf of the webapp author, which nicely reflects in the length of that article.

Comment: So, according what you are saying now, it means they are some ways in which a web application can make itself embeddable via a script tag.?? That's exactly what I'm trying to achieve..

Comment: What do you mean by "saying now" -- read the post again, I said "Some web applications/APIs offer a JSONP variant for embedding where you can indeed call them via a script tag". Gee, I'm trying to help you but somehow I feel I now need to defend myself. That's not fun to be honest.

Comment: I'm sorry if you feel that way, I'm just trying to understand you, so that I will know what to do..

Comment: how is your app hosted? Do you have a server backend that you have control over? If so then you can modify what you are sending from the server and instead of sending HTML you can send javascript code that uses `document.write` to write the same content where it is called.

Comment: My app is hosted on netlify, and there's no much Backend code, I basically just hosted it on netlify. And I don't really know if I can easily have control over netlify Backend..

Comment: I don't know netlify, but I suspect that you are right and won't have sufficient control over the backend.

Comment: Alright, is there any Backend you would suggest, I mean the one that I can easily have access to and achieve my aim with it..??

Comment: as long as you are running the server yourself (e.g., on aws of GCP) you can chose any backend you like. Personally I like meteor, or node.js + expressjs for small projects like this.

Comment: Hmm, would love to use Node.js, but the app is a react app, and I don't know how to use node.js with react, I use either firebase or netlify. Maybe I will probably have to find out how to use node.js with react..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226842/discussion-between-ogundipe-pelumi-and-christian-fritz).

Comment: read up about https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll use next.js, that way I'll be able to use node.js for the Backend which means that I will be able manipulate the Backend like you said I would need to in order to get what I want.

Comment: By far the easiest of the three is actually meteor (which is a node application).

Comment: I don't know how to use meteor, perhaps you can put me through??

Comment: Their react tutorial is really easy to follow.